# SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

**when i run the code it tell me :**

```
~/DiscordBot-Flash$ npm start
> djs@1.0.0 start /home/runner/DiscordBot-Flash
> node index.js

/home/runner/DiscordBot-Flash/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RESTManager.js:32
    const token = this.client.token ?? this.client.accessToken;
                                     ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'
```

i don't know how to fix that can some one help me please

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) and it is supported in node from 14.0.0

In their [docs](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js#installation) they write *nodejs version 16.6.0 or newer is required*

Fix: upgrade node version to at least 16.6.0

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution for the people who use repl.it
https://blog.abbasali.me/how-to-use-nodejs-v16x-on-replit

Comment: Be sure to include the relevant elements of the link you included, otherwise your answer will be deleted as a "link-only answer". Remember that link you provided might disappear in the future.